Get Downloadable Link with Hash
I'm trying to get the downloadable link with hash (like the one present in the email sent to the customer) from my block.
My idea was to call the getPurchasedLinkUrl method of the \Magento\Downloadable\Block\Sales\Order\Email\Items\Order\Downloadable class.
So, I tried this way:
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Block;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order;
use Magento\Checkout\Model\Session as CheckoutSession;


class Success extends Template
{
    protected $order;
    protected $checkoutSession;
    protected $downloadable;

    public function __construct(
        Template\Context $context,
        Order $order,
        CheckoutSession $checkoutSession,
        \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository,
        array $data = [],
        \Magento\Downloadable\Block\Sales\Order\Email\Items\Order\Downloadable $downloadable
    ) {
        $this->order = $order;
        $this->checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
        $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
        $this->downloadable = $downloadable;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    public function getDownloadableLinks()
    {
        $incrementId = $this->checkoutSession->getLastRealOrder()->getIncrementId();

        $order = $this->order->loadByIncrementId($incrementId);

        $items = $order->getAllItems();
        $downloadableLinks = [];

        foreach ($items as $item) {
            if ($item->getProductType() == 'downloadable') {
                $productId = $item->getProductId();
                $product = $this->productRepository->getById($productId);

                // Get the downloadable links associated with the product
                $extensionAttributes = $product->getExtensionAttributes();
                $links = $extensionAttributes->getDownloadableProductLinks();
            
                foreach ($links as $item) {
                    $downloadableLinks[] = $this->downloadable->getPurchasedLinkUrl($item);
                }
            }
        
            return $downloadableLinks;
        }
    }
}

but it says: Error: Call to a member function getOrder() on null in /var/www/magento/vendor/magento/module-sales/Block/Order/Email/Items/Order/DefaultOrder.php:26

Can you please try using getDownloadUrl($item) method of class \Magento\Downloadable\Block\Customer\Products\ListProducts
If this answer works as your expected, please mark it as accepted. That indicates your issue is solved and makes it easier for others with the same issue to find a verified answer. And that would be great if you click the upvote button for the answer in case you feel it is useful.

I tried to pass the class \Magento\Downloadable\Block\Customer\Products\ListProducts in the constructor but the class is not even initialized.
